# How do I get a post removed?

Tags: support, deletion

I have been asked by my University Mathematics department to remove a post that I made a while ago, how can I go about doing this?

Comment: It might be good to provide some extra information in your flag (what about the post does your maths department find objectionable?).

Comment: @user27182 I'm so curious to know what it was.

Comment: @GitGud So too am I.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the "flag" button underneath the post and explain to the moderators why you need it deleted.

[image: screenshot with "flag" link circled]

Comment: [Freehand circles, please](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/224469)...

Comment: It's also worth noting that the moderators are not _obligated_ to delete the post in a case like this.

Comment: I just noticed that you invited me to a chat. To make things short, I don't have a problem with red on white. I have a problem with red and green being mixed together, as well the problem with yellow or bright green on white, but still not with red on white.

Comment: Thanks. ${}{}{}{}$